# How to URL rewrite rule that works even when omitting the slash?

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to write a `.htaccess` URL `RewriteRule` that will allow the user to not typing the slash. However, it's not working.

Below is my code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cars(.*)
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://wwwlocal.example.com/$1 [P,NC,L]
```

When the user types in **http://www.example.com/cars**, the sub-domain should load from my http://wwwlocal.example.com/. It still shows http://www.example.com/cars/ on the user's browser; however, it's not. It's showing the page from http://wwwlocal.example.com/cars/ instead. In addition, images coming from **/cars/images/car1.jpg** do not load either with this rule.

Comment: Any other attempts on "RewriteRule making slash optional" or did you search for "CSS/images not working with pretty URLs" yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it working.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/cars/?(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://wwwlocal.example.com/$1 [P,NC,L]
```